# How to tackle a NoneTypeError?

Tags: python, list

I have a function which returns a list. But it has nothing to return. I want to handle the TypeError.
I have tried this:

```
def isLookingAround(lst):
    res = []
    body = []
    for data in lst:
        res += isLookingAt(normalize2(data))
        body += isBodyDirection(normalize2(data))


    if most_body == "front" or most_body == "backward":
        if ('lookL' in res and 'lookR' in res):
            return 'lookingAround'
    elif most_body == "left" or most_body == "right":
        if ('lookF' in res and 'lookB' in res):
            return 'lookingAround'
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "action_detector.py", line 201, in <module>
    write_labels(input_source, labels)
  File "action_detector.py", line 179, in write_labels
    for itr, word in enumerate(lbls):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I am still getting the error with labels.append(detectors.isLookingAround(back_Data))  . I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jerry Understand, but `l` is the list which is gonna get appended, and also it's empty, so maybe the OP has another list called `list` (not a good name)

Comment: @Jerry l is a separate list. It has nothing to do with the list.

Comment: Do not use keyword as a variable. Here : `list`

Comment: Forgot to add `)` : `l.append(detect.isSomething(data))`

Comment: I guess your issue coming from `detectors.isLookingAround(back_Data)`

Comment: @Jerry If it is NoneType is there a way I can handle this. Actually, this function is returning none. can I add some if statement?

Comment: But the thing is that appending `None` to a list does not generate an error. You will have to fix `isLookingAround` itself. Or alternatively learn when  `isLookingAround` gives the error so you can make sure `back_Data` does not cause that error.

Comment: @Jerry thanks. I will look into the isLookingAround( )

Comment: @prb Sure. FWIW, maybe removing the current code would be better since the error is not raised here.

Comment: Can you also include the full error? It's difficult to pinpoint where the error might be occurring because more functions are being used in `isLookingAround`.

Comment: @prb Are you sure this is the full error? The traceback does not mention any of the things you have shown in the question so far :(

Comment: @Jerry yes. I am sure. :(

Comment: @prb Do you know what is calling `write_labels`? Is it `isLookingAt` or `isBodyDirection` possibly?

Answer (score 0):

To check data is empty. you can use below code

```
if data:
   l.append(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to handle the `NoneType` exception, you can surround the statement within `try-except` blocks.

For example, you can do something like,

```
try:
    labels.append(detectors.isLookingAround(back_Data))
except TypeError:
    # Do something. Like,
    return
```

It will "catch" the error, and then you can handle it properly. However, the error seems to come from `isLookingAround` method.

You can re-check that, and if you're unable to resolve it, post a new question, I guess.

Comment: I have already tried this. I am not able to handle it. Maybe there is a problem with the function

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is occurring here? Maybe post a stacktrace here..